# Pyinstaller not working when binaries in spec file are modified

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to remove any windows dlls from the generated installer by modifying the binaries in the spec file, basically removing all dlls that start with "api"

```
a = Analysis(['PseudoDialog.py'],
             pathex=['D:\\PSY'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='PseudoDialog',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries = [x for x in a.binaries if not x[0].startswith("api")],
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='PSY')
```

This code fails with the error:

`SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression on the line`

```
a.binaries = [x for x in a.binaries if not x[0].startswith("api")]
```

I actually did not need to do this in the end. The problem was that I had noticed numerous warnings when running pyinstaller. It was looking for lots of windows dlls prefixed with "api-win-ms" and the job was failing.

I found a way to include these dlls by adding their location to the environment path variable. But then I realised that these files could change in a major patch, and worse, that it is forbidden to package windows dlls as part of a solution and deploy them on other machines.

In the end all I needed to do was ignore the warnings and run the project in a virtualenv to prevent pyinstaller grabbing loads of unnecessary packages and libraries.

Comment: Improved formatting

Comment: Those DLLs are for `Windows Kits` (CRT Library). These are needed if you need to run your app on windows without CRT libs (like Windows 7). No need to worry about them, but you can add those to your environment variables so PyInstaller would grab them.